# How to redirect traffic from squid to vpn?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, squid

I have a windows machine with a squid server and VPN client connection(which is not the default gateway)

What I want is to redirect some traffic from squid to my default ethernet connection and some to VPN.

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.11
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.1

PPP adapter vpn_conn:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.3.33
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

squid conf

```
http_port 2003
acl  user3_acl  myport 2003
tcp_outgoing_address 172.16.3.33 user3_acl

http_port 2004
acl  user4_acl  myport 2004
```

2004 port works as expected through my Ethernet adapter, but redirect to vpn doesn't work,

the log contains

```
1638648992.630     75 33.33.333.333 NONE/503 0 CONNECT docs.microsoft.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
```

I've managed to fix that with
`route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 172.16.3.33`

Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: is all the traffic you want to send out your Ethernet interface destined for endpoints inside your LAN?  can you show us what your route table looks like now? the route table is going to define how all this works, and its also the reason adding a route changed the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: No, it's a transparent proxy, only change IP address, but the aim is to serve traffic.

Comment: I'm not able to parse your response into an answer to my specific question. The reason I asked, is that it appears you have added a "default" route (a route to 0.0.0.0/0) to your route table, exiting your VPN interface. that will make all traffic go through the VPN, unless it's destination is listed more specifically in your IP route table with a different exit interface. Your route table almost certainly contains  a route listing for your LAN, so it makes  sense that traffic to the lan would exit the Eth and public traffic would go out the VPN. this is often called "split tunneling".

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it correctly.  Yes, I've created a second "default" gateway, but its metric was higher than the ethernet one, so it's not used by default.  The problem is that I don't understand how tcp_outgoing_address works. There was a specific route 172.16.0.0 to  172.16.3.33.  I expect that it should have worked. Why do I need to have 0.0.0.0 to 172.16.3.33? I guess because the final destination was some public IP that was requested initially and tcp_outgoing_address  just forwarded it to the next hop, but the rule work for final destination IP?